# Ext JS Combbox override - How to check a property is set before overriding it

Tags: javascript, extjs

We use Ext JS 2.3.0

I am trying to override a combobox "tpl" property but I want to override this if 
its not already set.

In our application combobox is widely used and a few new components have been created by extending combobox. So its important I don't override any custom settings.

So basically I want to achiveve something like this.

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
     if(!this.tpl){
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate( '<tpl for=".">',
                                    '<tpl>',
                                    '<div ext:qtip="{text}" class="x-combo-list-item">{text}</div>',                '</tpl>',
                                '</tpl>'
                                )
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.form.ComboBox` will only have `tpl` in its prototype if has has been set on the `Ext.form.ComboBox` class *itself*. Setting it on any classes *extended* from `Ext.form.ComboBox` will not affect the original. See it illustrated here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s3g

For checking whether `Ext.form.ComboBox` has `tpl` in itself, use:

```
Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype.hasOwnProperty('tpl')
```

Comment: Thanks @DrakeES. In our case the extended component has initList function which is getting triggered as soon as I focus on element. Now in that function there is a check `if(!this.tpl)`  and we set the custom tpl for extended component there. At the point this code is executed it has already inhierieted the tpl from original combobox and would not set the new one.